# How to restore list of calendars in Thunderbird/Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

In my Thunderbird/Lightning calendar view, the left-hand column is missing. I probably deleted it when I was looking for something else.

I cannot find anything in the menus or preferences to restore this column. The calendar view itself is fine, I can see my events, but I cannot choose which calendars to display.

Please help me to restore the list of calendars.

Mine looks like this [image: My calendar view]

It should look like this [image: Required]

Comment: You could try to reset the user interface and toolbars to default by starting Thunderbird in [Troubleshoot Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-mode-thunderbird) and choosing the needed options. Or remove (after backup) the file `localstore.rdf` in your Thunderbird profile folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your Calendar Pane that is missing.  In the upper-right click the menu button and navigate to View->Calendar->Calendar Pane->Show Calendar Pane and ensure Calendar List and Mini-Month are selected to restore your view as shown in your post.

[image]

Comment: That's it! It was easy once you gave me the name of the item.

Comment: Glad it helped. An upvote on the answer would be great if you found it helpful @Peterbill